# Assembling Word Doc using Data from Excel- MS Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-office-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have a questionnaire that users complete. It is in Excel.
After users complete the questionnaire I would like to be able to generate a Word document that contains their answers. For example "The answer to your question was [answer from Excel Questionnaire cell A49 ]"

I have seen that this is possible with Sharepoint. However, I don't have Sharepoint.
I am working on MS Office 2010. I also have visual Studio Express 2010.

What is the best way to achieve the above, pretty please?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for VBA then you should be asking this at Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps use the mail merge feature in MS Word? It wasn't originally designed for this, but you should be able to get exactly the results you need.

http://mistupid.com/technical/mailmerge/

Answer (score 1):

You may be long beyond this problem, but here are links towards a solution.

[This covers a range of options.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-simple-tips-for-using-excel-2010-data-in-word/851)

[This describes only one.](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/office-and-productivity-applications/9780132491709/sharing-information-between-programs/ch15lev1sec7)

Essentially, from Word 2010 use the Insert > Object button. Choose your Excel spreadsheet and then choose the range you want to select.

I am new to this process as well so I can't offer any advice about fine-tuning the formatting, but that should get you started on importing data from Excel.